# Calling a function with internal linkage via pointer from another translation unit

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers, linkage

Can we declare a callback function in an anonymous namespace (thus giving it internal linkage), knowing that it will be called from another translation unit (another library even)?

Some lib:

```
void register_callback(void (*cb)())
{
  ..
  cb();
  ..
}
```

Main program

```
namespace {
int foo_cb() { ... } // internal linkage
}

int main()
{
   register_callback(foo_cb);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: yes, it is ok

---

From [basic.link] (emphasis mine):

> 2. **A name** is said to have *linkage* when it might denote the same object,
>      reference, function, type, template, namespace or value as a name
>      introduced by a declaration in another scope:
>
>    - When a name has *internal linkage* , the entity it denotes can be
>        referred to **by names** from other scopes in the same translation unit.
> 3. [...]
> 4. An unnamed namespace or [...] has internal linkage. [...]. A name having namespace scope that has not been
>      given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing
>      namespace if it is the name of
>
>    - a function; or

So basically *linkage* is a property of **names** rather than of objects, functions etc. This means that a function declared inside an unnamed namespace cannot be called **by name** from another translation unit. There is no restriction to call it by it's pointer.

Comment: Good distinction of names vs objects.