# Is the call operator of lambdas required to have linkage?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, language-lawyer

I have some code that deal with address of functions, lambdas and template arguments.

Here's a snippet that shows to me some usage of these address to functions:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    auto l = []{};
    using L = decltype(l);

    // fine, am I just lucky?
    using type1 = std::integral_constant<decltype(&L::operator()), &L::operator()>;

    struct Bar {
        static void baz() {}
    };

    // error!
    using type2 = std::integral_constant<decltype(&Bar::baz), &Bar::baz>;
}
```

The thing is, for being able to send `&Bar::baz` as template argument, it must have linkage, hence the error.

Why the lambda case works? Is it because it is not static or because the call operator of the lambda has linkage?

Comment: test2 compiles fine for me in gcc. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: The member function pointer is a value, not a name.  Values don't have or need linkage.

Comment: Okay... This example don't seem to reproduce the issue. I got a code with me that output the error. My gcc version is 7.1.1. I'll edit the question

Comment: I got it sorted out. I got the error while taking the address of a static function defined locally in the main and trying to send it as template argument. It doesn't apply to lambdas. I'll delete the question since it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a dupe? I remember a long drawn out conversation about lambda linkage here before. I'll search for a bit.

Comment: @NirFriedman thanks. I searched but found nothing. However, I edited the question, my old code missed the "v" part in "mcve"

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot It will take some standardese logic chopping to verify, but there is a plausible argument that such a lambda should have internal linkage. Such a lambda is basically a local class, and members of local classes have "no linkage" (by which I assume they mean, internal linkage): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class.

Comment: As far as I can see the entire standard section on lambdas doesn't say a word about linkage, so maybe it is not specified. However, lambda must be allowed to convert implicitly to function pointer when it is stateless, and that function pointer could be returned into another translation unit and called. That means that the most logical implementation would likely be to give it external linkage, at the very least in the case where it's stateless, and probably for simplicity, in all cases.

Comment: @NirFriedman "no linkage" means no linkage.

Comment: @T.C. Ah ok, I clarified that for myself, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @nirfried the function pointer has to have the same effect as calling the `operator()` but they need not be the same thing.

Comment: @Yakk Well, my reasoning was that the most logical implementation would do so because *something* had to have external linkage to call a function pointer from other TUs. But my reasoning seems wrong too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442606/calling-a-function-with-internal-linkage-via-pointer-from-another-translation-un. So it seems like the linkage could just as easily be internal and not interfere with this. So at this point I'm not sure; I would think implementers would rather default to less linkage, so there must be a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure type of a lambda is an unnamed class, see [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.closure#1). A member function of a class has the same linkage, if any, as the name of its containing class; see [[basic.link]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.link#5). If the containing class has no name (not even for linkage purposes), then its member functions have no linkage.

Additionally, the closure type of a local lambda is a local class, and local classes, even those with a name, have no linkage; see [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.closure#2) and [[basic.link]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.link#8).

Before C++17, the linkage requirement, found in [[temp.arg.nontype]/1.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.arg.nontype#1.3), applies to pointers and references, but not pointers to member. Under these rules, GCC is correct in accepting your lambda case and rejecting your `Bar::baz` case.

[N4268](https://wg21.link/n4268) removed the linkage requirement entirely for C++17 while revamping the rules for template non-type arguments. In C++17, both examples should be accepted.